# How can I avoid circular reference errors when serializing EF Core results?

Tags: c#, json, .net, entity-framework-core

I have the following entity models set up in my EF Core project:

```
public class ForumPost
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    // ...some other properties
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    // ...some other properties
    public List<ForumPost> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

So I have a many to many relationship between posts and tags. I have **no** relationship configuration in my `OnModelCreating`.

My context is setup as follows:

```
public class ForumsContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ForumPost> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

When I query my `ForumsContext` as follows:

```
 var posts = await context.Posts.Include(p => p.Tags).ToListAsync();
```

EF automatically populates the `Posts` field for each of the `Tag` objects in each of the `ForumPost` objects in `posts`. I cannot figure out why this is happening and if I was to serialize the `posts` list above to JSON it would throw an exception due to the object cycle (`Post->Tags->Posts->Post`).

Why are the tag's post lists being populated? How can I tell EF to not populate this list.

Comment: So the problem has nothing at all to do with EF Core, it's about JSON and circular references. Which JSON library are you using? JSON.NET? System.Text.Json? You can find questions asking how to handle circular references for either one

Comment: And a very, very good advice is to *not* use your data model as your response model. Except for very simple cases each one requires different relations, different fields. There may be fields you don't want to show in any JSON model, either because they're noise (eg audit fields like `Created`) or sensitive, like credit card numbers

Comment: Which .NET Core version are you using? System.Text.Json can [handle circular references in .NET 5 and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-5-0). You could also add the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to `Tag.Posts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just how Entity Framework works. The `Include` call populates the navigation property on both sides of the relationship.

Entity Framework conventions dictate that you must have navigation properties on both ends of a many-to-many relationship.

It does not appear to be possible to only have one navigation property using the fluent API, either. The code below does not work, and in asking whether there is a way to avoid defining the property for one of the entities, in this thread [the team answered with "Not yet"](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19003#issuecomment-735314438).

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ForumPost>().HasMany<Tag>(post => post.Tags).WithMany();
```

##### JSON object cycles

As for object cycle errors when serializing to JSON, [these can be handled or ignored in .NET 5 or later.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-5-0)

[This article](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/03/15/fixing-json-self-referencing-loop-exceptions/) goes into more detail on the issue, and shows a solution for NewtonSoft.Json.

I'm not a fan of this solution. You'll end up with `null` properties where the serializer stopped because it encountered a cycle.

But all of that is beside the point. You don't need to change your data model or JSON serializer settings to get around this issue. The issue is that you're exposing your data model in the first place.

##### Suggestion: use response models

The proper solution is to map your entities to response/view models or DTOs instead. This allows you to format proper responses, and it allows your data model to evolve without interfering with your response model.

Example:

```
public class ForumPostResponse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class TagResponse
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

You could also format `ForumPostResponse.Tags` as a list of `string` instead, in case you only want a list of tag names on forum posts, and include the description in other responses. Anything's possible.

You do need to write extra code to handle the mapping between objects, but it's a small tradeoff for a much nicer and more maintainable design. And besides, there are several libraries that simplify the process, the most popular being [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

Comment: The linked article is only valid for .NET Core 3. Since .NET 5 [circular references can be handled through a serializer option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-5-0)

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I will probably turn to AutoMapper!

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not be the best solution for circular reference on serialization, but an workaround can be initializing the list property:

```
public class ForumPost
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    // ...some other properties
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; } = new List<Tag>();
}

public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    // ...some other properties
    public List<ForumPost> Posts { get; set; } = new List<ForumPost>();
}
```

Also, due to initialization, you can manipulate those lists without worrying about null exeptions and all that stuff. But note, there might be a better solution for this problem.

Comment: I don't think this gets around the serialization issue, but it is indeed a good way to avoid null reference exceptions.

Comment: You can try it out, it does cancel circular reference on serialization

Comment: @DorinBaba it does not cancel circular reference when using .include